# jQuery - if div has two words, strike through first word

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jQuery which looks at a div, and strikes through the first word. This works fine, however if that div only has one word I dont want it to strike through.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Code:

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(index) {

//get the first word
var firstWord = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];

//wrap it with strike
var replaceWord = "<strike>" + firstWord + "</strike>";

//create new string with span included
var newString = $(this).html().replace(firstWord, replaceWord);

//apply to the divs
jQuery(this).html(newString);
});
```

Comment: How about the good ol'`if`?

Comment: check the length of `$(this).text().split(' ').length > 1' and then do the striking off stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(index) {

// get the word array
var words = $(this).text().split(' ')

if ( words.length === 1 ) {
    // nothing to see here
    }
else  
    {
    //get the first word
    var firstWord = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];

    //wrap it with strike
    var replaceWord = "<strike>" + firstWord + "</strike>";

    //create new string with span included
    var newString = $(this).html().replace(firstWord, replaceWord);

    //apply to the divs
    jQuery(this).html(newString);
    }

});
```

Comment: If this was the right answer please don't forget to click the check mark to indicate that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the several possible conditions to check that there is actually a second word and run your code only then. One example is this:

( As suggested by [AB Udhay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6027953/ab-udhay), it's always better to use trim() before splitting it in this manner. )

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(index) {

var words = $(this).text().trim().split(' ');
//get the first word
var firstWord = words[0];

if( typeof words[1] !== "undefined" )
{

//wrap it with strike
var replaceWord = "<strike>" + firstWord + "</strike>";

//create new string with span included
var newString = $(this).html().replace(firstWord, replaceWord);

//apply to the divs
jQuery(this).html(newString);
}//if there's second word also
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant check `$(this).text().split(' ').length > 1`, like this code

```
jQuery('.class').each(function(index) {

    if($(this).text().split(' ').length > 1){

        //get the first word
        var firstWord = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];

        //wrap it with strike
        var replaceWord = "<strike>" + firstWord + "</strike>";

        //create new string with span included
        var newString = $(this).html().replace(firstWord, replaceWord);

        //apply to the divs
        jQuery(this).html(newString);

    }

});
```